# website page command (and syntax) to download file from AWS s3 to user's download bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website and a file on AWS s3.  When a button on the website is clicked, I would like the file in the s3 bucket to be downloaded to the user's download bucket. The AWS docs say to use one of 4 options to download (s3 console, AWS CLI, AWS SDK, Rest API)[ [[aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html#download-an-object)]].

I assumed the CLI is the way to proceed and tried (no errors, just doesn't work):

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket abcde --key folder/version/current/xyzapp.exe %userprofile%\downloads
```

Questions:

1. Is the CLI the way to proceed? If so, do I need to embed AWS CLI onto the webpage somehow?
2. What is the proper syntax (quotes, spaces, etc.) for the webpage code
3. Is the user's download bucket path correct?

1

Comment: If the s3 object is public, you can use the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to fetch the object via the "download url" shown on the AWS console.   "embed AWS CLI onto the webpage somehow" no.  There's a JS SDK but you don't need it if you're just fetching a public file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can access it via the URL, like this:

```
https://abcde.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/folder/version/current/xyzapp.exe
```

However, this would require the bucket to be made Public, or the object to be made Public.

Alternatively, you can keep everything private and generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3.